# Ошибка подключения к бд, когда имя пользователя задано кириллицей

Tags: node.js

Использую [node-postgres](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres). Кластер СУБД создан в кодировке WIN1251 с локалью Russian_Russia.1251.

```
var pg = require('pg');

var config = {
  host: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 5432,
  database: 'testbase',
  user: 'тест',
  password: ''
};

var pool = new pg.Pool(config);

pool.connect(function(err, client, done) {
  if(err) {
    return console.error(err);
  }
  console.log('Connected');
});

pool.on('error', function (err, client) {
  console.error(err.message, err.stack)
});
```

Если имя пользователя на латиннице, то подключение идет штатно. Если же user задан кириллицей (как в примере), тогда выдается ошибка:

```
{ error: role "тест" does not exist
    at Connection.parseE (C:\Users\vbuser\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:554:11)
    at Connection.parseMessage (C:\Users\vbuser\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:381:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\vbuser\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:117:22)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:548:20)
  name: 'error',
  length: 93,
  severity: 'FATAL',
  code: '28000',
  detail: undefined,
  hint: undefined,
  position: undefined,
  internalPosition: undefined,
  internalQuery: undefined,
  where: undefined,
  schema: undefined,
  table: undefined,
  column: undefined,
  dataType: undefined,
  constraint: undefined,
  file: 'miscinit.c',
  line: '433',
  routine: 'InitializeSessionUserId' }
read ECONNRESET Error: read ECONNRESET
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1026:11)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:569:26)
```

Пользователь 'тест' в бд создан и через консоль подключается без проблем.
Версия PostgreSQL 9.3, node-postgres 6.1.2.

Подскажите в чем проблема.

Comment: Проверьте кодировку в файле и в базе. Они должны совпадать.

Comment: Так тоже не работает. Да и странный это вариант, в общем случае я могу не знать кодировку бд. Да и зная, я, что должен каждый раз править кодировку в файле.

Comment: Не удается побороть проблему. Какие еще варианты ?

Comment: у меня нет ответа. возможно, самым простым решением будет использовать только английские символы для имени и пароля.